# Angular not working on Rails app once deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, deployment, dependency-injection

My rails/angular1 app works perfectly fine locally, but when I push it up to heroku, angular no longer works. The app is able to deploy, but on the app, I'm visually seeing the "handlebars" and variables on my page instead of the data displayed. I implemented the array notation for the controller dependencies. I even tried the ng-annotate rails gem. I still can't get angular to work on heroku. Here's my controller:

```
    /* global angular */

(function() {
  angular.module("app").controller("studiesCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.setup = function() {
      $http.get('/api/v1/studies').then(function(response) {
        $scope.studies = response.data;
        $scope.orderAttribute = 'compensation';
        $scope.isOrderDescending = false;
        console.log($scope.studies);

      });
    };
    $scope.changeOrderAttribute = function(inputAttribute) {
      if (inputAttribute === $scope.orderAttribute) {
        $scope.isOrderDescending = !$scope.isOrderDescending;
      } else {
        $scope.isOrderDescending = false;
      }
      $scope.orderAttribute = inputAttribute;
    };

    $scope.getSortIcon = function(inputAttribute) {
      if (inputAttribute === $scope.orderAttribute) {
        if ($scope.isOrderDescending) {
          return '\u2193';
        } else {
          return '\u2191';
        }
      } else {
        return '';
      }
    };


  }]);
})();
```

Is there something wrong with my controller code, or could the problem be elsewhere?

Comment: Open developer tools and check what are the errors that you are getting?

Comment: So in the console, I get this error: ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token```  and it points to ```application-0dcea3c445d3924c884387192680bee39be4e55187ce05a7c763e35990a83abd.js:45086 ``` which is the JQuery library js file. Also get the error ```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://quikk-study.herokuapp.com/%7B%7B%20study.image%20%7D%7D ```. I'm wondering if that narrows it down at all. Thanks!